# Transforming date format in python

Tags: python, time, datetime-format, python-datetime

I want to convert this date format 2020-07-24T19:49:58+03:00 in timestamp.

I have  tried with datetime but without success:

```
data="2020-07-24T19:49:58+03:00"
print (data)
date_time = datetime.datetime(data, '%Y %m %d %% %H:%M')
#date_time = datetime.datetime(data).isoformat()
print (date_time)
```

with the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dateparse.py",
> line 17, in <module>
> date_time = datetime.datetime(data, '%Y %m %d %% %H:%M') TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: You should make life easier on yourself since your string is in ISO format : `datetime.fromisoformat(data)`

Comment: Thank you... exactly what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

**Enter this Code:**  `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S')`

'27-07-20 Mon 10:10:30'

**Enter this Code for (today's date):** `datetime.date.today().strftime('%y-%m-%d')`

'27-07-20'

**For Object** : `datetime.datetime.now().date() datetime.datetime.today().date()` `datetime.datetime.utcnow().date() datetime.datetime.today().time()` `datetime.datetime.utcnow().date() datetime.datetime.utcnow().time()`